# Pygame <specified object> object is not a callable when trying to spawn more than 1 enemy

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

I have managed to create a way to access each enemy in a list and detect if its been hit... I think... Besides the problem. My problem is that every time I want to create more than one enemy I get the error "Enemy is not a callable object"

I honestly don't know whats going wrong here. Ive looked on other posts and one similar post shares something about "making sure I don't make my object = anything else". However my object isn't called anywhere else other than where it is being added to the list.

Outside the loop

```
Enemies = []
print("Enemies at start: ",len(Enemies))
```

It returns "0"

Creating the enemy inside the while loop

```
if len(Enemies) <= 5:
    Enemies.append(Enemy(random.randint(0,500),-50,70,70))
        #Spawns an enemy while the list is still less than 5 not really relevant and should be removed after code below is fixed.
    print("Enemies at creation point: ",len(Enemies))
    for Enemy in Enemies:
        #Enemies.append(Enemy(random.randint(0,500),-50,70,70))
        print("Created")
        if Enemy.health <= 0:
            Enemies.pop(Enemies.index(Enemy))
            print("Destroyed")
        else:
            print("Skipping")
```

Error: 'Enemy' object is not callable

I expect the output to simply spawn these enemies on the screen at random positions. While 5 do not simultaneously exist. So at the start, it will not spawn anymore enemies. However when one is destroyed, a new one is spawned.

Comment: Note how you create a variable called `Enemy`, then attempt to use `Enemy` as a class name to construct an object. Just change the loop variable (you should be using lower-case for your variable names anyways).

Comment: where do you define class `Enemy` ? I see only variable `Enemy` in `for Enemy in Enemies` so you replace class definiton with normal variable. Don't use `Enemy` as variable in `for`. There is also good rule - we use names with first upper letter only for class name but not for instances and variables. So better use `for enemy in enemies`

Comment: BTW: Pygame has class `Sprite` to create object like enemy, and class [Group](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) to keep sprites. When you have sprite in group and you use [sprite.kill()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill) then it will remove sprite from group automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is you use the same name for class definiton `Enemy` and variable in `for Enemy in Enemies`

There is good rule in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to use lowercase names for variables and camel case names (with first upper letter) for class names

So you should rather have

```
enemies = []
print("Enemies at start:", len(enemies))


if len(enemies) <= 5:
    enemies.append(Enemy(random.randint(0,500),-50,70,70))
        #Spawns an enemy while the list is still less than 5 not really relevant and should be removed after code below is fixed.
    print("Enemies at creation point: ", len(enemies))
    for enemy in enemies:
        #enemies.append(Enemy(random.randint(0,500),-50,70,70))
        print("Created")
        if enemy.health <= 0:
            enemies.pop(enemies.index(enemy))
            print("Destroyed")
        else:
            print("Skipping")
```

As you can see I use `Enemy` only in `Enemy(random.randint(0,500),-50,70,70)`. In other places I use `enemy`

BTW: even editor in SO know this rule and it uses light blue color to show class `Enemy` and make code more readable.

Comment: Thank you however a new problem has arisen. It isnt reading if the enemy's health is less than 0...

Comment: Its the same code block, im talking about the part where it does "for enemy in enemies:", After finishing creation it appears to ignore the block entirely.